# How to create a B2C tenant for existing Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My current directory doesn't have a B2C Tenant, so following this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) to create one for my existing SPA app to fully utilize AZ AD B2C, such as allowing Apple, Google and Twitter authentication.

1. Registered AzureActiveDirectory in current (Default directory)
   [image]
2. Upon creating a new AZ AD B2C tenant, entering my current domain name resulting "Already in use by another directory", I'm forced to create it in a new directory.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would Suggest you to try with another **uqniue or weird** name, Might be the custome domain you are trying to to use its already been using by another Azure AD tenants.

Getting the same error like you while creating the Azure AD b2c tenants.

[image]

If I have given some unique name like this able to validate successfully.

[image]

***Note :  If you are trying to create a B2C directory rather,you need to have a subscription associated with the account.***

You can refer also refer this [***Microsoft Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/564494/azure-ad-always-says-34already-in-use-by-another-d.html) Discussion where someone already encoutred the same issue.

You can also refer how to create a [***Azure AD b2c Tenant***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) in default Azure Active Directory Tenant.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's not about uniqueness. It's about why can't use my current existing directory (I'm already in)? For example, I currently have one directory `xyz`, logically a new B2C tenant should be created in it. It won't as "already in use" **by myself**. This is the concept I think MS needs to explain.

Comment: Azure Active Directory B2C tenant that you are creating is independent and seperate from the intial Azure AD tenant that you are logged on to. therefore Azure AD b2c tenant that you creating has it own Azure AD services and independent to the one that you created earlier. But you can access that both these tenant since they are registered in the same subscription. Either you should have your custom domain name regsiter on Public DNS server or intial domain name you are using should be unique with regards to **.onmicrosoft.com** domain.

Comment: Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit weird but it actually worked for me and I could make another tenant with the same name

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

[image]